# Using DATEDIFF(type, startdate, enddate) with values that come from other tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

All of the examples that are online are getting the `DATEDIFF()` using values that are hard coded.

I want to get the `DATEDIFF()` from 20 or 30 rows in a table that have columns named `startdate` and `enddate`.

The end goal for me is to get seconds between two dates for 20 rows... I created a variable above and `SET` the variable equal to `DATEDIFF(SECONDS, startdate, enddate)`, but when I go to grab the values in the table that is holding the start and end date, I am getting errors.

Is there something I'm doing wrong, logically anyways?

Comment: Please post your code

Comment: If you get errors, post the error + the exact code you're using. If this is a duplicate of your other question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35088126/finding-the-average-of-a-date-in-sql-server) please remove one of them

Answer (score 1):

You made seconds plural. Try datediff(second, startdate, enddate) - should work just fine.